# Warning messages when using DataStax java drivers

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I'm using the latest DataStax Java Drivers for Cassandra 2.0.3.  I get messages shown below every time I start my application:

```
 SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
 SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
 SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

The drivers seem to work fine despite the messages.  Is there anyway to get rid of these messages.  I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Oracle Java version 1.7.0_45.

Comment: Which version of driver are you using??

Comment: Try using sl4j-API jar in your classpath and see

Comment: I've updated to all current versions (Cassandra 2.0.6; DataStax driver version 2.0.1; jlf4J-api-1.75.jar), and still seeing the same messages.